# Executing CMD commands using C++

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, 32bit-64bit, wow64

I am trying to sleep my PC using this command

```
system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\psshutdown -d -t 0");
```

it works fine if I use cmd, but when I run this in cpp, I got this

```
'C:\Windows\System32\psshutdown' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

32-bit applications running on 64-bit Windows will be put under [file system redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector). Therefore if your app is a 32-bit one, the call `system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\psshutdown -d -t 0");` will look for `psshutdown.exe` in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` and failed. You have some solutions:

- Use *Sysnative* instead to access the real *System32* folder:

  ```
  system(R"(C:\Windows\Sysnative\psshutdown -d -t 0)");
  ```
- [Turn off file system redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-wow64disablewow64fsredirection) explicitly (should be avoided in general)
- Or better **recompile your app as a 64-bit application**